# How to make buttons in Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

There was information that the buttons will be added soon.
This feature is available to some, but so far only in Python.

How to do this on Discord.js???

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You will have to wait until the master branch implements it

Comment: This is an undocumented feature known as "Desktop Bot UI Kit Buttons". It will not show even if you manage to send the right format to the API unless you use a client mod against the TOS.

Comment: A quick search yields this: https://github.com/v-briese/discord-bot-gui-testing

Comment: The Discord client experiment for "Bot UI Kit Buttons" was added in April 2021, but has been removed since build 2a314b2ec9ed999e2b523f9439a8cb8be43305c7, released on 19th May. There is no official documentation regarding this feature.

Comment: Update: Buttons have been added to the developer documentation, see https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (2023):** Use this package only if you're using discord.js v12, V13+ have them [`built-in`](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html)

You can use the package for buttons [`discord-buttons`](https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons)

All packages above have been copied by us....

Answer (score 0):

https://discord-buttons.js.org/message-button

There's a npm:
`npm i discord-buttons`

Answer (score -1):

The best package so far is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-buttons)

You must use the command `npm i discord.js-buttons`